# curl: (7) Failed connect to www.google.com:80;

Tags: windows, curl

I have installed [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/downloads) and got cURL automatically.

```
C:\>curl --version
curl 7.30.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.30.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.7
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s
 rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI libz

C:\>bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.0(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

C:\>grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.4.2

Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

After installing, when I tried

```
C:\>curl http://www.google.com
```

I didnt get back the html tags back. I got the following error,

```
C:\>curl http://www.google.com
curl: (7) Failed connect to www.google.com:80; No error
```

Please can anyone help,How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you solved this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had the same here. Turns out that it was my firewall (LittleSnitch on Mac).

But my Firewall only blocked curl connections on port 80. So the wget command was working.  E.g. `wget google.com` – loads a index.html into you current folder. I’m on Mac, so i don’t know if this is also available on Windows.

And i was also able to download the file via my browser.

You could test wget, test your browser and then check if the `curl` is working on your url in another network, to make sure that it's not caused by the firewall’s network.

Answer (score -2):

I wish I could remember the poster to properly credit him/her but this is the advice, "Load GE even if you get the black screen and to to "Tools" (in google not windows browser) then select "Options" then select the "General" tab and find the "Network" area and uncheck the box which states "Use HTTPS for Google connections"...then "OK/Apply" it and reboot GE. That'w what worked for me.

Envirodan

Comment: how is curl related to Chrome?